# How to dynamically set State using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have defined set of states using react hook useState and i need to set those state based on dynamic(responseData i.e array which is holding all errors) values.
[image]

Below pic is the response i am getting from **yup library** function call
[image]

Below is my code please go through the code

```
function SignUp(props) {

  const [basicErrors, setBasicErrors] = useState({
    email: false,
    firstName: false,
    lastName: false,
    password: false,
    acceptedTerms: false,
  })
  const [basicValues, setBasicValues] = useState({
    email: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    password: null,
    mobile: null,
    acceptedTerms: false,
  })

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("basic-values",basicValues);
      e.preventDefault()
      signUpValidationSchema
        .validate(
          {
            email: basicValues.email,
            firstName: basicValues.firstName,
            lastName: basicValues.lastName,
            password: basicValues.password,
            acceptedTerms: basicValues.acceptedTerms,
          },
          { abortEarly: false }
        )
        .then(function(responseData) {
          console.log("form validation", responseData);
          })
        .catch((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData.inner);
          for (let i = 0; i < responseData.inner.length; i++) {
            setBasicErrors({ ...basicErrors, [responseData.inner[i]['path']] : responseData.inner[i]['message']})
          }
          console.log("form validation error", basicErrors);
        })
    }

    return (
    
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect()` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this task.

Assuming that you fetch the validation error array from backend into your React component's prop variable named `validationErrors`, `basicErrors` can be dynamically set as follows:

```
const [basicErrors, setBasicErrors] = useState([...]);
const validationErrors = fetchValidationErrorsAPI();

useEffect(() => {
  setBasicErrors(validationErrors);
  // syntax [ValidationErrors] means that
  // this effect will execute everytime variable
  // 'validationErrors' changes.
}, [validationErrors])
```

After this effect is executed, your component will re-render and `basicErrors` updated.

Comment: I am using yup library to validate my form, it returns array of errors as shown in above pic.

Comment: @BahubaliAk you can connect your API call that uses your library to the `validationErrors` variable as in the code structure above and it will work.